# How to perform analysis on a group in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset of cars. The dataset contains make (Brand) of the car, the model name of the car, year of manufacture and the current market price.

```
|Make|Model|mfgYear|price
|Audi| A4  | 2007  |3429999
|Audi| A5  | 2008  |2900000
|Audi| A5  | 2009  |3000000
|Audi| A4  | 2011  |4000000
.......
```

I wish to know, for each make-model combination (or make-model group), what is the average rate at which the price goes down every year. E.g. if the group is make->Ford, model->Focus, I'd like to know at what rate the market price goes down as the car gets older.

The following code does the grouping and shows what the first two groups look like.

```
gb = df.groupby(['make','model'])
for (name, group),i in zip(gb,range(3)):
    print name
    print group


('Audi', 'A3')
    |make |model  |mfgYear |  price
19  |Audi |   A3  |  2014  |3300000

('Audi', 'A4')
     |make| model | mfgYear  |  price
20   |Audi|    A4 |    2014  |3100000
406  |Audi|    A4 |    2012  |1799000
```

Any help will be appreciated. I think this question may be in the province of cluster analysis, but I'm not too sure about it.

My target is ...

```
|Make|Model|averageAnnualDepreciation
|Audi| A4  | <average of (priceCorrespondingToMostRecentYear - price)/(mostRecentYear - year)>
|Audi| A5  | <average of (priceCorrespondingToMostRecentYear - price)/(mostRecentYear - year)>
....
```

Comment: what is output you are expecting? May be for `('Audi', 'A4')`

Comment: You should also include a sample of your input data, or some dummy data of a similar type in the question

Comment: Average percentage or average amount?

Answer (score 1):

For this DataFrame:

```
   Make  Model  mfgYear    price
0  Audi   A4       2007  3429999
1  Audi   A5       2008  2900000
2  Audi   A5       2009  3000000
3  Audi   A4       2011  4000000
4  Audi   A5       2007  2500000
5  Audi   A4       2010  3200000
```

I group:

```
gb = df.groupby(['Make','Model'])
```

Now I can apply a function:

```
def avg(group):
    year = group['mfgYear']
    price = group['price']
    last_year = year.max()
    last_price = price[year == last_year]
    other_prices = price[year != last_year]
    other_years = year[year != last_year]
    down = ((last_price.values - other_prices) / 
             (last_year - other_years)).sum() / len(other_years)
    return down

gb.apply(avg)
```

which gives this result:

```
Make  Model
Audi   A4      471250.125
       A5      175000.000
dtype: float64
```

This corresponds with numbers for `A4` calculated by hand:

```
((4000000 - 3200000) + (4000000 - 3429999) / 4) / 2
471250.125
```

Comment: This is a much better, more pythonic way of doing it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Each of these two groups, alias `group' in the for loop, are dataframes. For each of the groups - i.e. for each of the dataframes -  What I did was...

1. Sort by mfgYear in the descending order.
2. Fix the first mfgYear as the base year and the corresponding price as the base price.
3. Apply a function to each of the subsequent rows of the dataframe that will give the depreciation relative to the base-year,base-price. This should be put in a set or a list. Used group.apply()
4. Average the values in the aforementioned set.

I constructed a separate dataframe with one column as "make", another as "model", and a third one "average yearly depreciation". What this really boiled down to was how to sequentially apply a function to rows of a dataframe.

```
df_result = pd.DataFrame()
gb = df.groupby(['make','model'])
for (name, group),i in zip(gb,range(3)):
    print name
    gp1 = group.groupby('mfgYear').mean() # This gives the mean price of every year
    gp1 = gp1.sort_index(ascending=False)
    depreciations = gp1.apply(<func for cal. depreciations>)
    data = {}
    data['make-model'],data['annualDepreciation'] = name,depreciations.mean()
    df_result.append(data,ignore_index=True)
```